# Selecting Data from Joomla SQL Table where any value is the variable

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to select data from my database where any value in the columns id, name, username or email is the variable description. When i do this, I get an error 1054 saying the column for the value in $description is unknown - error shown below. What am I doing wrong?

Please note: The variable value used in the jinput is defined further up in the code, and as shown in the error below, it is properly assigned a value.

Thanks in advance

My code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$description = $jinput->get('value', null , null);
$db->setQuery(" SELECT * FROM #__users WHERE MATCH(id, name, username, email) AGAINST ($description) ORDER BY #__users.name ");
$db->execute();
$results = $db->loadObjectlist();
```

This is my error:

```
Unknown column 'Ben' in 'where clause' SQL=SELECT * FROM tud_users WHERE MATCH(id, name, username, email) AGAINST (Ben) ORDER BY tud_users.name
```

Comment: You probably will want to enclose `$description` into quotes.

Comment: Tried that, it causes a server error

Comment: What server error? You probably didn't escape your quotes.

Comment: This isn't very informative. Anyways i recommend you to escape your quotes like `\'$description\'`

Comment: Thats all the error tells me - It doesnt tell you anything else. Okay thanks I shall try it like that

Comment: Causes the same issue as at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote your description variable to avoid this error and sql injection vulnerability.

Here is the modified code :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$description = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getString('value','');
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__users WHERE MATCH(id, name, username, email) AGAINST (".$db->quote($description).") ORDER BY #__users.name ");
$db->execute();
$results = $db->loadObjectlist();
```

Use JFactory::getApplication()->input->getString('value',''); to retrieve the value you want.

Always quote content with the Joomla method $db->quote();